# How do I create partition while installing Ubuntu on HP 840 g1?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Trying to install Ubuntu on my [HP 840 g1](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03961746#AbT0), alongside Windows 10, but encountering a problem where the installer cannot detect the hard drive.

I have this in my disk management

[image: here is a screenshot of my disk management]

Comment: That model could have seven different drives from the factory, plus (if any) whatever was added after delivery. In Windows, do `Win-R dskmgmt.msc {Enter}` and find what you have, then click [edit] and add the information to your original question.

Comment: i have added the screenshot of my disk management page, see if have suggestions on that

Comment: Is it old style MBR with 4 primary partitions?

Comment: Yes it is!. The issue is that Ubuntu installation does not detect these partitions, even when i create a new free partition, it wont be recognized.